# Update SQLite database online

Tags: database, visual-c++, sqlite, c++-cli, lan

I coded an application using C++/CLI and SQLite3, I would ask about how can I do the following:

Suppose that I uploaded SQLite database to a LAN, where any end user (uses my application) can check his database whether it was updated or not. If not, I want to add ability of adding the new records to the user database. What I want is some thing similar to AntiVirus software, the user can check the database online every day. I want the key points.

Comment: Do not use SQLite for network applications, especially if the database is not read-only.

Comment: @sad_man: I know that SQLite is not designed to be shared in a network, but If I would do that what will be the problem?

Comment: @Adban: SQLite is not very very good at multi-threading because of its database level lock. [Read this.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use a versionNumber field to check against

Answer (score 1):

You should add a TimeStamp field to all tables, which is filled with the actual creation time of the record (via your programm or an autovalue).

You customer program can then select the newest entry in his database, gets the TimeStamp and selects all entrys that are newer in the online database and add all newer ones to his database.